# How to activate assignment rules using controller's save method?

Tags: visualforce, assignment-rules, dmloptions

I have a `Visualforce Page` that overrides standard `New Case` page. It uses the `Case StandardController`, along with a controller extension.

The page has an `<apex:commandButton action={!Save}/>` line, referencing the standard save method in the controller. In my extension's constructor, I've added the lines:

```
        this.caseRec = (Case)stdController.getRecord();

        Database.DMLOptions dmo = new Database.DMLOptions();
        dmo.assignmentRuleHeader.useDefaultRule= true;
        caseRec.setOptions(dmo);
```

However, this is not causing the case to follow assignment rules.

Most code examples I've found online show similar code to the above, followed immediately by an `insert caseRec;` DML statement. However, since I am using the standard save method instead of overriding it, I don't have any DML statements in my controller extension.

I'm wondering if my issue is due to me setting the DMLOptions var in my extension, when the insert statement is actually happening in the standard controller's Save method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply overwrite the `save` method in your extension:

```
public static final String RETURL_PARAM = 'retUrl';
public PageReference save()
{
    caseRecord.setOptions(dmo);
    try
    {
        insert caseRecord;
    }
    catch (DmlException dmx)
    {
        ApexPages.addMessages(dmx);
        return null;
    }
    String retUrl = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get(RETURL_PARAM);
    return String.isNotBlank(retUrl) ? new PageReference(retUrl) :
        new ApexPages.StandardController(caseRecord).view();
}
```

The [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_std_actions.htm) on `StandardController` seems pretty clear that all the method does is save and redirect:

> `save`   Inserts a new record or updates an existing record if it is currently in context. After this operation is finished, the save action returns the user to the original page (if known), or navigates the user to the detail page for the saved record.

Note that the redirection will pull a return url if it is available in the page parameters, but will otherwise simply redirect to the detail (view) page for the saved record.

Comment: Adrian, I had considered overwriting the method, but my concern is with capturing all the functionality the standard save method provides. How do you know that your proposed code handles everything the standard method does?

Comment: Through experience. You need to make sure you don't redirect if there is any `DMLException`, but other than that you just have to save and then redirect to the view page.

Comment: Note, I would just wait to set the `DmlOptions` until you actually try to save. No need to add even that minimal data to the view state.

Comment: Going back to my original question, does this mean I cannot use the std controller's Save method and still enforce assignment rules? While I appreciate your experience, I'd rather not risk an overwrriten method failing to interact with the rest of SF's random functionality in the same way as the standard method. If SF provided some documentation on overriding the standard method that would provide a lot of peace of mind, but I can't find any...

Comment: You are correct, you cannot use the standard functionality afaik.

Comment: I agree the documentation on the save method doesn't mention any other functionality. Guess I've been burned too many times by hidden pitfalls in Salesforce's design. Thanks for fleshing out your answer.